# Detailed steps to configure Okta as an IDP in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We want to integrate OKTA as an IDP for Azure AD. Our requirement is when a user tries to access the application. They'll be challenged with a login page, which will be validated by Okta. Post this authentication, the authorization will be taken over by Azure and upon successful authorization, user will be shown a landing page of application. I checked following links to setup IDP in Azure AD but didn't come across detailed steps/procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/direct-federation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/azure-ad-b2b-collaboration-direct-federation-with-saml-and-ws/ba-p/735133) in order to get the more detailed explanation and also how the work flow is.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_4JIdaOq373YJZfD&Q_CHL=gl
>